# How to bring both old and new vale in single row in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

Create table query

```
CREATE TABLE ID_TAB (
    ID VARCHAR2(20),
    ID_VALUE VARCHAR2(20), FLAG VARCHAR2(20)
);

CREATE TABLE FACT_TABLE (
    ID VARCHAR2(20),
    VALUE VARCHAR2(20),
    NAME VARCHAR2(100)
);
```

Insert Query

```
INSERT INTO ID_TAB VALUES('100','ABC','N');
INSERT INTO ID_TAB VALUES('120','ABC','Y');

INSERT INTO FACT_TABLE VALUES('100','MAX','ORANGE');
```

My objective is to update the fact table 'ID' column to 120 because it has the FLAG value as 'Y'

My original table has 50 million records.

How can we write the query in merge or using Update?

Comment: . . I don't fully understand the logic.  How is id 120 chosen?

Comment: You need to be clearer about your intention here and perhaps show a few more examples of before and after data.

Comment: the new value is taken based on the value of FLAG.If the value of FLAG is 'Y' then we consider it as new value and we will update in the fact table.

Comment: Basically ID_TAB is a dimension table

Comment: Can you guarantee there's exactly 1 record for a specific ID_VALUE having the flag set to 'Y'?

Comment: yes we will have only one value as 'y' for a specific ID_VALUE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following (I didn't try it though):

```
UPDATE fact_table
   SET fact_table.id = (SELECT yes_tab.id
                          FROM id_tab no_tab
                          JOIN id_tab yes_tab
                            ON no_tab.id_value = yes_tab.id_value
                           AND yes_tab.flag = 'Y'
                         WHERE no_tab.id = fact_table.id)
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   id_tab
               WHERE  id_tab.id = fact_table.id
                 AND  id_tab.flag = 'N');
```

The `WHERE EXISTS` makes sure you update only the elements with the flag in the corresponding ID_TAB set to 'N'.
The query for the `SET` searches the ID of the corresponding element having the flag set to 'Y'.

Comment: Thanks its working.Since it will have more than 50 million records,joining ID_TAB table more than twice will degrade performance. Can we able to do joining within twice

Comment: @anand19 you may use a dedicated `UPDATE` based on the *dimension* date, with no need of join - see my answer.

Comment: Hi Marmite...in this case we cant trust date as an option

Answer (score 0):

To get a performant solution (i.e. avoid the join completely) you may switch to a dynamic SQL.

I extended you example a bit to have more updated keys as follows.

Note that there is maximal one new value per `ID_VALUE`, but more old value with `N` flag are allowed, which all must be updated.

```
INSERT INTO ID_TAB VALUES('100','ABC','N'); -- old key
INSERT INTO ID_TAB VALUES('110','ABC','N'); -- old key
INSERT INTO ID_TAB VALUES('120','ABC','Y'); -- new key
INSERT INTO ID_TAB VALUES('200','EFG','N'); -- old key
INSERT INTO ID_TAB VALUES('210','EFG','N'); -- old key
INSERT INTO ID_TAB VALUES('220','EFG','Y'); -- new key


INSERT INTO FACT_TABLE VALUES('100','MAX','ORANGE');
INSERT INTO FACT_TABLE VALUES('110','MIN','ORANGE');
INSERT INTO FACT_TABLE VALUES('200','MAX','APPLE');
INSERT INTO FACT_TABLE VALUES('210','MIN','APPLE');
INSERT INTO FACT_TABLE VALUES('220','NEW','APPLE');
commit;
```

The `UPDATE` statements reflects all th eupdate options, e.g. the keys 100 and 110 should be chnaged to 200.

This leads to the following update

```
update FACT_TABLE
set ID = case 
when ID in ('100','110') then '200'
when ID in ('200','210') then '220' 
end
where ID in ('100','110','200','210');
```

Note that the where condition consist of all the keys with flag `N` and the `case statement` is produced per `ID_VALUE` mapping all keys with the flag `N` to the (only one) key with flag `Y`.

This makes the generation of the UPDATE statement an easy little task of a query on the table `ID_TAB`. See the query below. For the list creation the function `LISTAGG` is used. The main parts are commented in the query.

```
with old_keys as (
select  /* get list of all old values */
listagg(''''||ID||'''',',') within  group (order by ID) old_keys
from  ID_TAB where flag = 'N'),
case_stmt as (
select ID_VALUE,
listagg(case when flag = 'N' then ''''||ID||'''' end,',') within  group (order by ID) old_keys,
max(''''||case when flag = 'Y' then ID end||'''')  new_key
from  ID_TAB  
group by ID_VALUE),
case_stmt2 as (
select 
'when ID in ('||OLD_KEYS ||') then ' ||NEW_KEY ||' /* update for '|| ID_VALUE || ' */' case_when, ID_VALUE
from case_stmt),
case_stmt3 as ( /* concatenate CASE WHEN */
select listagg(CASE_WHEN,chr(13)) within  group (order by ID_VALUE) case_when from case_stmt2)
select 
'update FACT_TABLE
set ID = case 
'||
case_when ||
'
end
where ID in ('||
(select old_keys from old_keys)||')' as update_stmt
from case_stmt3
```

On the sample data this SQL string is returned

```
update FACT_TABLE
set ID = case 
when ID in ('100','110') then '120' /* update for ABC */
when ID in ('200','210') then '220' /* update for EFG */
end
where ID in ('100','110','200','210')
```